# Handling serialized string without duplicate values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ajaxmethod that serializes my form:

```
$(document).on("click", "#prescription", function () {
$("#PersonBMIright").removeAttr('disabled');
if($("#AbdominalCircumferencerightradio:checked").length === 1) {
    $("#AbdominalCircumferencerighttext").attr('disabled', true);
}
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Overview",
        type: "post",
        data: { form: $("form").serialize(), answerData: maincontent },
        success: function (result) {
            $('.content-wrap').html(result);


        }
    });
```

The problem is that ive got one textbox and a radiobutton that works togheter so that when the radiobutton is checked the textbox should not have a value and the opposite. But when i serializes the form and the radiobutton is checked the textbox will be in the serialized string but without a value and that makes my deserializemethod to create an error because it gets two values of the same kind. Is there a way to get ridd of the textbox before i serialize it? Ive tried to make it disabled just before i serializes it but that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if($("#AbdominalCircumferencerightradio").is(":checked")) {
    $("#AbdominalCircumferencerighttext").prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: It gets disabled but it will still send textboxvalue as "" and that will make the error

Comment: I use this code to deserialize it and it is here it gets the error.    var data = formName.Split('&')
                         .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                         .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
I didn't work to remove the name of the attribute